# Is there a way to resolve type synonyms in haskell?

Tags: haskell, types

When you create a type synonym with `type`, ghc/ghci will use it instead of the original type whenever it is used explicitly, but will never attempt to work backwards from an inferred type to a matching synonym. Getting the most "abstract" synonym for a type would be pretty handy to learn complicated applications and libraries, which define synonyms for monad stacks and possibly synonyms of synonyms.

Has anybody ever written such a piece of code? I imagine it would be backtracking and it would also generate some spurious candidates (e.g. if two types are aliases of String, then they will both be candidates whenever a String must be resolved), but it could be useful in certain situations.

Comment: I've been toying around with the exact same idea, because this would be really useful for `pipes` and `lens`.  Ideally you would specify some sort of compiler pragma that acts like a rule, matching a pattern in an inferred type and rewriting it to the equivalent type synonym (with some sort of precedence if there are multiple matches).

Comment: I'm reminded of a blog post I read a few days ago which mentioned "Chthulu's type signatures": http://joelt.io/entries/yesod-in-production

Comment: it sounds like something good for a gsoc or similar

Comment: I gave it a quick look. Language.Haskell.Exts is a good starting point that is at least able to extract all declarations, their arguments and the module they belong to. Unfortunately it seems to be a purely syntactical analysis, so partially applied type signatures such as `type A = Either B`, which are potential candidates for reduction, are not covered. Any pointers?

Answer (score 2):

Not an answer, but a question. Type synonyms are often used to nicely name types in "high level code", but as soon as you pass those types into lower level/helper code (that are defined in terms of more concrete types), how should the system keep track of which synonym applies? consider the following:

```
type Title = String
type Name  = String

capitalise :: String -> String

my_title = "Mayor" :: Title

shouted_title = capitalise my_title :: ???
```

How does the typechecker know that the String going into heleper function `capitalise` is conceptually the same type as the String coming out of `capitalise`? In the presence of multiple type aliases, how should the type checker choose which to use?

Answer (score 0):

The Frege compiler, IDE and REPL try to do this for type applications (except applications of (->)) when they are asked to show "nice" types, and it does work in most cases. Here is an example [online session](http://try.frege-lang.org/) snippet:

```
frege> type Flubber = (Int, Double)
frege>  x = (42, 3.0)
frege> :t x    
Flubber
frege> y = [x,x,x,x]
frege> :t y
[Flubber]
```

So, in principle, it should also work in Haskell (perhaps modulo certain extensions in the type system relative to Haskell 2010).

Keep in mind, though, that - as @Thomas pointed out in his answer - there may be multiple ways to unsubstitute type aliases and hence the output may actually be misleading.